# Setting request parameters dynamically in struts.xml in struts2

Tags: struts2

I have some variables in my action class.

Now I want to redirect to another action by setting those variable values as request parameters. How I can do this?

I'm trying to do it like this:

```xml
<result type="redirect">myProfileShow?param1=${value}&param2={value2}</result>
```

It is not working.

Comment: Define "not working"; if `myProfileShow` is an action you should be using a `redirectAction` result. If there are publicly-available `getValue()` and `getValue2()` methods, I don't see anything immediately obvious.

Answer (score 2):

```
<result type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">myProfileShow</action>
    <param name="param1">${value}</param>
    <param name="param2">${value2}</param>
</result>
```

where `value` and `value2` should be declared in the Action class. You can also set hard-coded values for `value` & `value2`.

```
    <param name="param1">10</param>   <!--  param1 will be 10 --!>
    <param name="param2">15</param>   <!--  param2 will be 15 --!>
```